# Merge existing PDF with dynamically generated PDF using TCPDF

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am generating a PDF document using TCPDF. My requirement is to merge an existing PDF content at the last page of the dynamically generated PDF.

Comment: Can you please share some code you already have? We can help you update it.

Comment: So you want to append (or insert at the end) one PDF to/of another PDF. I find the the word "merge" misleading here, you should consider to change it. Additionally: you should show us the code you've tried without or with partial success.

Comment: require_once('../PDFMerger/fpdi/fpdi.php');
            $pdfm = new FPDI();
            $PDF = 'path to pdf';
            $pageCount = $pdfm->setSourceFile($PDF);
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $pageCount; $i++) {
                  $tplx = $pdfm->importPage($i,'/MediaBox');
                  $size = $pdfm->getTemplateSize($tplx);
                  $pdfm->AddPage('P', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
    $pdfm->useTemplate($tplx);$pdf->Output($ono.'-'.$fy.".pdf", 'I'); $pdf  is the object of TCPDF which is used to create the page

Comment: @T.G Please don't post larger code snippets as comment. You can edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the best solution to your problem is to use `FPDI`.

https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI

The way it works is that `FPDI` extends `TCPDF` so you can work with an `FPDI` object using all of the methods that you're used to using with `TCPDF`, but with the additional methods that you need to import pages from existing PDF files (`setSourceFile`, `getTemplateSize` and `useTemplate`).

It looks a bit daunting to set up, but if you're using Composer it is actually incredibly easy. Just add `setasign/fpdi` and `setasign/fpdi-tcpdf` to your `composer.json` file and then use an instance of `FPDI` in place of your `TCPDF` instance. I found I didn't even have to call `class_exists('TCPDF', true)` as mentioned on the github page. Once I added those other entries to `composer.json` and ran `composer dumpautoload` it just worked.

Comment: Please note: PDF version > 1.5 is only supported by commercial addon

Answer (score 1):

This is still in development for TCPDF: http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF__IMPORT.html#a5a9effc936e8fa461c0f6717c2d10d93

If possible you can use ZEND:

```
require_once 'Zend/Pdf.php';

$pdf1 = Zend_Pdf::load("1.pdf");
$pdf2 = Zend_Pdf::load("2.pdf");

foreach ($pdf2->pages as $page){
    $pdf1->pages[] = $page;
}

$pdf1->save('3.pdf');
```

If you are running on Linux, you can also run a shell command.

```
<?php
exec('pdfjam 1.pdf 2.pdf -o 3.pdf'); // -o = output
```

You can install pdfjam from here: http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic/firth/software/pdfjam/pdfjam_latest.tgz

Comment: For others looking here, the Zend PDF library seems to be abandoned: http://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the free version of FPDI but does not support PDF version 1.5 or above.

If someone else is looking for a free solution I have used TCPDI. You can find it on github.

My project does not use composer, so I used the master branch from https://github.com/pauln/tcpdi 
If you are using composer, you can find some fork for composer too. Just search tcpdi on github.

Once you add it to your project, the code is quite simple.

This is a snippet from my code. I used it to save a copy of the privacy policy (a static pdf) with the user name and agreement date in footer.

```
// Create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDI(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
...
// Add the pages from the source file.
$pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($localPrivacy);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) {
    $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($i);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx);
    // Add agreement text in document footer
    $pdf->SetXY(15,282);
    $pdf->Cell(180, 5, "Documento approvato da {$fullName} il {$date}", 0, 0, 'C');
}
// Send PDF on output
$pdf->Output(FOLDER_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{$userId}.pdf", 'F');
```