# Combine two TCPDF documents

Tags: merge, concatenation, tcpdf

I'm using TCPDF to create two separate reports in different parts of my website. I would like that, in the end of the first report, the second report should be loaded.

It's different than import a PDF file, because the second report is also generated by TCPDF. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your question that what you ultimately want to provide is one PDF file that consists of the first PDF concatenated with the second PDF.

One quick and dirty solution is to utilize the `pdftk` command line PDF processor and call it from within your PHP code using the `exec()` function. The `pdftk` command has many features and concatenating files is only one of them, but it does an awesome job. Depending on your hosting situation, this may or may not be an option for you.

The other option would be to use `FPDI` to import the two PDF files and concatenate them within your PHP code and then send the concatenated version to the user.

More information on using `PFDI` here:

[Merge existing PDF with dynamically generated PDF using TCPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969828/merge-existing-pdf-with-dynamically-generated-pdf-using-tcpdf/33988723#33988723)

Given that you're already using TCPDF, importing the pre-existing file that you want to concatenate with the one you've just created shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: the two PDF files are dynamically generated by TCPDF, what I want is a way to merge them

Comment: FPDI is an extension to TCPDF that provides the ability to import an existing PDF file and add those pages to a PDF file that you're in the process of building with TCPDF. It doesn't matter if the first PDF was created by TCPDF or by some other method. The point is, unless I'm missing something, FPDI will solve your problem. Did you read the answer that I linked to in my solution? If that isn't going to solve your problem, can you explain why?

Comment: FDPI has a method `setSourceFile('document.pdf')` that can be used to import an existing PDF file. That's no problem if the FIRST file is generated by TCPDF, the problem is that the SECOND file is also generated by TCPDF, I need something like `setSourceFile('generatedPdf.php')`, There's nothing like this in the documentation of FPDI

Answer (score 0):

Just add FPDI to your project/composer from:

https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/

Can you still used tcpdf. 
FPDI support all the methods of tcpdf, just used new FPDI() instead new tcpdf() the result will be the same in your report, after you create your report marge the files with the code from this page:

https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/

In a loop, once set the first file and after this set the second... 
If you will need help i am here for you.

Comment: Please NOTE: PDF version > 1.5 is only supported with commercial addon